# Unable to restrict unique random generation to required output

Tags: php

I want to restrict the unique numbers to be only 8 characters long with my prefix.
Here is what i do

```
$prefix             =  "CEVO";
$u_unique_id        =  str_shuffle(md5(uniqid(rand(100000,999999), true)));
$user_unique_id     =  $prefix.$u_unique_id;
```

But this code isn't restricting to 8 characters. Where i am wrong?

Comment: str_shuffle doesn't trim string. Read manual first.

Comment: Ok, but help me in the issue of restricting characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP [`md5()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php):

> Returns the hash as a **32-character** hexadecimal number.

Use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) to limit that to the desired length, so in your case `8 - 4 = 4`;

---

```php
<?php

$prefix             =  "CEVO";
$u_unique_id        =  str_shuffle(md5(uniqid(rand(100000,999999), true)));
$user_unique_id     =  $prefix . substr($u_unique_id, 0, 4);

echo $user_unique_id;
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6WgKDUts0IBGdgqKCg5u4b5K1lzqZTGl@ZlFpamxmemIEkXlxTFF2eUpqXlpGrkpphqgNRkpmgUJealaBgagICOJRho6iiUFJWmampqgswqTi1CMw5oFswFegrFpUlAgzWQ7dRRMNBRMAFq5kpNzshXQDPC@v9/AA)